# Formik form not rendering

Tags: reactjs, formik, tsx

Just setting up a basic bonehead form for learning purposes and ... can't seem to render.  No errors.  Functional component runs.  Just nothing to see...

MyForm.tsx

```
export const MyForm: React.FC = () => {

    console.log("MyForm has been called")
    return (

        <div>

            <Formik initialValues={{ firstName: "roberto" }} onSubmit={data => { console.log(data) }}>
                {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, handleBlur }) => {
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <TextField value={values.firstName} onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} name="firstName" />
                        <pre>JSON.stringify(values)</pre>
                    </form>
                }}

            </Formik>

        </div >
    )
}
```

I've imported MyForm properly into App.tsx, and MyForm is currently all I'm returning from App.tsx.

No errors. Just nothin...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you're *returning* your form which is why it's not rendering:

```js
export const MyForm: React.FC = () => {

    console.log("MyForm has been called")
    return (

        <div>

            <Formik initialValues={{ firstName: "roberto" }} onSubmit={data => { console.log(data) }}>
                {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, handleBlur }) => (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <TextField value={values.firstName} onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} name="firstName" />
                        <pre>JSON.stringify(values)</pre>
                    </form>
                )}

            </Formik>

        </div >
    )
}
```

Note that I changed the function's curly braces to parens around your `<form>`. Alternatively, you could leave the curly braces and instead

```js
{({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit, handleBlur }) => {
  return (<form>...</form>)
}}
```

Comment: ughh thats annoying.  But thank you!  The explicit/implicit returns curly braces combo is pesky.